# How to specify "OR" conditions for Gmail filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

How can I filter messages in Gmail using boolean `OR` conditions? For example, I can specify addresses in the `To:` or `From:` fields, but this only matches emails that meet both criteria. How can I match emails that meet one or both criteria?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Type into the search field of Gmail:

```
from:xyz OR to:uvw
```

see also [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8931).

to make a filter (and apply actions to that filter) from that search: click the little down arrow on the right side of the search field and then click `create filter with this search`.

Comment: Thanks. You've saved me a lot of frustration. I have a friend who doesn't know about the BCC field and likes to email TONS of people who like to reply-to-all.

Comment: At first I thought this answer is correct, but now I see that OP asked about filtering,  and you said "type into the search field." Now my vote goes to Senseful. Good, succinct answer, though!

Comment: @LimitedAtonement: i do not understand your comment.

Comment: @akira The OP asked about filtering email messages (which I read to mean applying inbound filters), and your answer is about searching for email messages.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement: so, all you need to be happy is a "after the search click 'create filter'" statement somewhere?

Comment: @akira Yup. I considered editing the answer, but it was aptly answered below.

Comment: To clarify for anyone who might run into this: "OR" is case sensitive (i.e. "or" won't work).

Comment: This can also be written as from:(xyz,uvw) if you want to filter multiple values for the same parameter.

Comment: Looks like the comma-separated parameter values @SandeepC mentioned aren't currently working

Comment: from:(abc@def.com OR zyx@def.com) is the gmail preferred format if you're wanting to create filters. And as kevinmicke mentioned above the OR is case-sensitive.

Comment: For multi-word filters, make sure to surround them in quotes, for example: `"Hello World" OR "Foo Bar"`

Answer (score 69):

If you are talking about searching, then @akira's question is correct. However, it sounds like you are asking about how to use this condition in a filter.

The trick is that you can put whatever search criteria you want in the filter's **Has the words** field. For any other field it will prefix your criteria with the field name. For example, if you type `user@example.com` in the **To** field, it'll create the filter condition `to:(user@example.com)`. The reason it works in the **Has the words** field, is because it doesn't prefix it with anything. This is because it acts as a normal search on the content of the email.

1. Create or modify a filter.
2. In the **Has the words** field, enter your `OR` condition. For example: `to:user@example.com OR from:user@example.com`

This is also the place to put [any other attributes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/when-is-it-okay-to-use-label-in-or-is-in-a-gmail-filter) you want to match (e.g. `label:`, `in:`, etc.).

This will also work in the **Show search options** page, however it's easier to just use a normal search instead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using the workflow in akira's answer does not work, because the search criteria get mangled as soon as you click on "create filter with this search". Advanced boolean expressions are left untouched only when using the "Has the words" field, like suggested in this answer.

Comment: Use **Has the words** field is the correct one. Ex:
`from:info@some-domain.com OR to:info@some-domain.com`

Answer (score 56):

To my surprise, the solution to me was using the vertical bar `|` between emails instead of the comma `,` in the `TO` filed during filter creation.

Example:

```
name1@domain.com | name2@domain.com | name3@domain.com`
```

The search box would look like:

```
to:(name1@domain.com | name2@domain.com | name3@domain.com)
```

I got a popup message from Gmail saying that using special characters may give unexpected results. Just clicked on continue and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 34):

Gmail accepts several syntaxes:

`apple OR orange
apple | orange
{apple orange}`

Personally, I like to use the curly braces because it is nice and concise. The following are all equivalent:

`from:{john jane joe}
{from:john from:jane from:joe}
(from:john OR from:jane OR from:joe)`

Answer (score 13):

You can group them:

{"Words1" AND "Words2"} OR {"Words1" AND "Words3"} etc...

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've got to work for the `to` field is:

```
to:({first@email.com second@email.com third@email.com})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `has the words` input field instead. This will let you update existing filters instead of deleting and creating new ones.

Example:
`from:(sas.com) OR to:(sas.com)`

Answer (score 2):

Either `A OR B` and `A | B` work for me.