# When is it okay to use "label:", "in:", or "is:" in a Gmail Filter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

When you try to use any of the queries `label:`, `in:`, or `is:` in a Gmail filter, you will see the following warning:

> Warning: Filter searches containing
>   "label:", "in:", or "is:" criteria are
>   not recommended, as these criteria
>   will never match incoming mail.

However, if you want to [disable the spam filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-do-i-disable-the-spam-filter-in-gmail), you can safely ignore this warning. Are there any other exceptions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Filters are [processed in the order they exist in the list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/in-what-order-are-filters-processed-in-gmail). This means that if a filter comes after another one, you can use one of these special filter criterias which it warns you about. For example, if you have a filter that stars a message, then you can have a rule below it use `is:starred` successfully.

Some criteria is even applied automatically before filters are processed. Examples are messages that are sent to spam (i.e. you can use `is:spam`), or a POP3 account which labels incoming mail. In this case the filter's order does not matter.

Here is a list of criteria you can use:

- `is:starred`: if a previous filter has starred the message, this can be used.
- `is:spam`: if the message was automatically marked as spam, this criteria can be used.
- `is:read`: if the message's read property was not modified (i.e. it stays unread), this will not match it. If a previous filter marked a message as read, this will match it.
- `is:unread`: the opposite of `is:read`.
- `label:example`: if a previous filter has labeled a message this can be used. (Note that mailboxes such as the inbox will work. That is, `label:inbox` will work.)
- `label:user@example.com`: if your mail account is set to read another account via POP3 and is set it to automatically label all email from that account, the `label:` criteria can be used since it will first label the message and only then run the filter.
- `in:trash`: you would think that if a message is trashed from an earlier filter, the other filters would stop working, however, that is not the case.
- `in:inbox`: the two things that affect this are "Skip the inbox" and "Delete it".
- `in:anywhere`: it's pointless, but it works.

Criteria you cannot use:

- `in:sent`: When you send a message, it will first process the filters and only then be considered `sent`, thus, you cannot use the `in:sent` criteria in a filter.

Untested (I will update this as I test these):

- `is:muted`
- `is:chat`
- `is:important`

Comment: Can you apply a filter on outgoing messages before they are sent?? Can you give an example?

Comment: So If I understand you correctly then:

Filter: Apply Label
Filter: Use Label

... works, but then if you later add:

Filter 2: apply same label

... then this will be broken until you delete the "use label" filter and recreate.  Is that about right?

Comment: For me doing a filter with is:spam and then forward to external email, doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a warning message for people unaware that those keywords are reserved and have special behavior.

Comment: I don't think it is, because of the part that says `these criteria will never match incoming mail`... meaning you are using these expressions to filter Gmail on purpose. I understand why it most likely won't match, since when a new email arrives, it won't have a label. But [what if you have another filter that adds a label](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/what-happens-if-multiple-filters-match-an-email-in-gmail)?

Comment: Doesn't a new message have the label:inbox associated with it?