# Why is my email labeled and sent to a folder in Gmail instead of the inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a custom label in Gmail that sends mail I want to look at about once a month to a folder labeled "JUNK". The filter tells the emails to skip the inbox, mark the emails as read, and label them as "JUNK".

I've noticed that a few months ago, my emails from Scotiabank regarding interac email transfers were being labeled as Junk. Undesirable behaviour! I looked in my filter settings, but nothing there indicates why this mail is being sent there. As far as I can see, none of my filters should result in messages with Scotiabank's information being sent to "JUNK".

Is there a way to determine why a specific email is being sent to a folder through a label filter? When I try to remove the label "JUNK" from the email, it still won't show up in my inbox.

If there isn't a way to do this, how can I force these emails to go to the inbox?

I looked at this post ([Force email to stay in inbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/gmail-filters-labels-force-email-to-stay-in-inbox)), but I think it assumes I actually know why my mail is being filtered to "JUNK" in the first place.

This is the first time I've posted here, so please let me know if I can add any information to my post.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way within Gmail itself to find out which filters (why) Gmail used to filter a particular email. Logic would seem to suggest there must be something about the filter/email that resulted in the email being filtered - particularly since the `JUNK` label is being applied. However, there can be other reasons why the email is not in the inbox... for instance, do you have "categories" enabled?

Comment: It might help if you shared your filter and the headers from one of these messages.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this is your only filter that moves things to the "JUNK" label?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a very old  troubleshooting question related to a specific Filter and OP has not shared the filter rule nor responded to requests for additional detail.