# Is there a way to automatically ban an address in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

In Yahoo! Mail, in the settings section, we have an item named "banned addresses", which means that we normally don't receive email messages from that address. It doesn't go to spam, trash, etc. We just don't receive it.

But in Gmail, blocking an address means sending messages to the spam folder. 
And if you create a filter for that address and choose the item `delete it`, it just goes to the trash folder.

So you have the chance to open spam and trash folders and see the message. Is there a way like banning a certain address in Gmail?

Answer (score 3):

With Gmail as-is, no, there is no option to filter messages so that they're permanently deleted automatically.

Frankly, I think this is a good thing, as Gmail filters can be very powerful. Could you imagine the kerfuffle if people had filters deleting messages from addresses that they actually wanted to receive without informing them or allowing them to recover the messages?

Any message in Spam or Trash gets deleted 30 days after it hits that destination.

If you just want to use just Gmail, you could save the URL of a search for the offending address and use that to find and delete permanently any messages that come up. Gmail has a spot where you can save handy URLs. You can also perform the search by simply modifying the filter.

Otherwise, you'd need to use a third-party client of some sort to automate permanent deletion of messages.

---

Related:

- [How to permanently delete Gmail spam?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85571/354)
- [How can I auto-delete some spam from Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31042/354)
- [Gmail permanently delete a message via a filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8993/354)

Comment: but yahoo has this service and it's not so kerfuffle, Gmail can has this feature besides it's filters and so complete service. I mean sometimes you get stuck in a relationship, that you just can't stop the temptation of reading the gmails and you cannot delete your account,too

Comment: That's as may be, but Gmail doesn't offer this.

Comment: so what kind of third-party client? And where's that spot of the gmail to save handy urls?

Comment: Beats me. Maybe a browser extension. Maybe a desktop client like Thunderbird. As for the links, I can't get to Gmail at the moment to provide a screen shot or the official name of the feature. Shouldn't be difficult to find, though.

Comment: so is there a way to permanently delete gmail's copy when you automaically forward it?

Comment: No, there isn't.