# Stop Gmail from running all filters

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Has anyone figured out how to get Gmail to stop processing filters once a condition is met? I would like to avoid having certain messages potentially get multiple labels. As great as Gmail is, the filtering option is quite primitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This sort of answers my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/when-is-it-okay-to-use-label-in-or-is-in-a-gmail-filter/5037#5037). You can't stop filters from processing once a condition is met, but you can add a filter to filter messages that have been filtered, which will do in my case.

Comment: This was helpful. I have a variety of messages coming from the same email address but with different text in quotes in the From header. I set up rule #1 to apply the label "noise". Then I set up rule #2 to exclude messages with that label (with -label:noise) and apply its own label.

Answer (score 4):

If you label your messages in previous rules, you can use "has:nouserlabels" condition in further rules to exclude already processed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `NOT` functions in your filter. 
Say you have a, b and c as keywords for your labels:

- filter1: `a` `-b` `-c`  > everything from a
- filter2: `-a` `b` `-c`  > everything from b
- filter3: `-a` `-b` `c`  > everything from c

but of course, this is a hassle in case of many filters

Comment: This is fine if you only have a few filters, but if you have say 50, putting in those not conditions becomes unwieldy.