# How to create filter rule in Gmail that marks certain spam messages as read?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

In Gmail, this search produces the desired results: `in:anywhere from:(onmicrosoft.com) mcafee`.

I see plenty of unread spam.

I want to create a filter rule with that query and tell Gmail to either delete those spam messages automatically or at least mark them as read. I don't want to see any of those spam messages as counted in the unread spam counter.

But when I click Create Filter, a modal then says:

> Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g. "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming mail. Do you still wish to continue to the next step?

When I accept, it automatically converts my query to `from:(onmicrosoft.com) label:ast mcafee` which then does *not* produce the desired results.

How can I achieve my goal?

P.S. Less important but I'm also curious: What does `label:ast` mean?

Answer (score 0):

I will accept an answer that offers more explanation, but I just noticed that when I created this other variation: `from:(onmicrosoft.com) is:spam mcafee` it then converted to `from:(onmicrosoft.com) label:spam mcafee`, and that version seems to work.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/5037/27487 was helpful.